# How to get a specific string from string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, str-replace, split, substring

Here is my string 'ABCDEF-24-04-07-001' and all **i want is to get last string separated by -(hyphen) i.e. 001.**

But another complexity for me that, the above string may vary i.e. it may be 'ABC-24-07-01' OR 'ABCDE-24-07-010' OR 'ABCDE-24-07-1'.

Please help me to get solution for the above problem

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(32) = 'ABCDE-24-07-010';
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),0,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string))))
```